# How to make a 3D plot with surfaces

Tags: r, matlab, 3d, plotly, scatter-plot

I am trying to make a 3D plot with surfaces in R, something similar to this.

[image]

The above plot is generated using Matlab (https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/264427-making-10-2d-slices-out-of-3d-plot).

I created a 3D scatter plot in Plotly, but now I need to create a landscape out of it for viewing it better. By landscape I mean to select the highest point in scatter plot and then generate something like a that looks like what seen in above picture).

To demonstrate I am using a dummy dataset.

```
mtcars$am[which(mtcars$am == 0)] <- 'Automatic'
mtcars$am[which(mtcars$am == 1)] <- 'Manual'
mtcars$am <- as.factor(mtcars$am)
plot <- plot_ly(mtcars,x = mtcars$mpg,
     y = mtcars$disp,z = mtcars$am,
     color = ~mtcars$am, size= 1,
     colors = c('darkolivegreen3', 'darkorange3'))
plot
```

This generates a plot like this

[image]

[image]

Comment: you can put something together with the `rgl` package.  What have you tried so far ("provide me with the R library" sounds a bit like "give me the code" ...) ?

Comment: @BenBolker thanks for responding..don't quote me wrong.. I am just looking for the right library to try it out my own. I started with plot_ly and created a 3D scatter plot, and I was expecting there will be a function or something which will do the smoothing of the peaks. But there is none. Here is what I have so far

Comment: plot= plot_ly(d,x = d$x,y = d$y,z = d$z, color = ~d$z, size= 1,colors = c('darkolivegreen3', 'darkorange3','darkorchid3','gold3','deeppink3'))

Comment: not 3D but a good alternative would be to use `ggridges`

Comment: @GordonShumway Thats perfect. But it won't be having y axis right ?

Comment: (1) what do you mean by "smoothing of the peaks"?  (2) Can you give a [mcve]? (3) If you edit your question just a little bit, to phrase it as "how do I do this" rather than "what package can I do this with" (even if the latter is what you expect as an answer), I will vote to re-open ...

Comment: @BenBolker Sure I am working on a reproducible code, will update question soon :-) Thank you

Comment: @BenBolker I did edited the question to the best I can, I tried to google it a lot and couldn't find anything that help me to achieve what I am doing. Thats why I posted here as last resort. I feel no one has tried this before , or maybe its not possible with plotly..

Comment: @BenBolker Looks like its still in hold.. Do you think I have to create another post